# Apple Watch and Swift crashes while calculating the device motion with CoreMotion

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, core-motion, devicemotion

Currently using the Apple Watch to calculate its yaw, pitch, and roll angles.

However when trying to use the Core Motion functions, the app crashes. Has anyone experienced this problem?

```
if motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable{
    self.referenceAttitude = self.deviceMotionManger.attitude
    let currentAttitude : CMAttitude = self.deviceMotionManger.attitude
    currentAttitude.multiplyByInverseOfAttitude(self.referenceAttitude)
    self.Yaw.setText( "Yaw " + String(format: "%.1f", currentAttitude.yaw))
    self.Pitch.setText( "Pitch " + String(format: "%.1f", currentAttitude.pitch))
    self.Roll.setText("Roll " + String(format: "%.1f", currentAttitude.roll) )
}

else {
    self.Yaw.setText("device motion is not" + String(motionManager.deviceMotionActive))
}
```

Comment: Crashes with what error?

Comment: The comment below answered my question. None of the other sensors are functional on the apple watch. @zoul

Answer (score 2):

The only Core Motion data available from the Apple Watch is raw accelerometer data.

The watch won't provide raw gyroscope data, raw magnetometer data, or processed device-motion data; [`deviceMotionAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/deviceMotionAvailable) will always return false.

As for a crash, you would get a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when the outlet for your implicitly unwrapped `Yaw` label is not connected to the storyboard.

Comment: How can I use the accelerometer data to get the yaw, pitch, and roll of the device? @PetahChristian

Comment: You could try some [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=accelerometer+device+motion+%5Bios%5D+answers%3A1), but it's really not practical or possible using raw accelerometer data alone. You may want to [submit a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).